# What does systemd do if you issue two `systemctl restart $some_service` commands simultaneously?

Tags: linux, systemd

If one process runs `systemctl restart something.service`, and a second process also runs `systemctl restart something.service` a bit later (but before the first command has returned), what does systemd do?

Will the second `restart` "wait" for the first to finish and then issue a new restart? Or will it essentially have no effect if a restart is already underway? Or something else?

Comment: Probably the second request would be queued. Will have to check code to confirm though.

Comment: I imagine that will also (somewhat) depend on the service unit definition, what [`Type=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#Type=) is used, is there an [`ExecStop=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=) definition or not and maybe more. But satisfy your curiosity and simply run [`parallel -j #number systemctl restart something.service`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

A restart will queue a stop job and a start job. By default, all jobs are queued using 'replace' mode; this means that if the unit is already starting, it will be immediately stopped (aborting any startup in process), then started again.

With separate start/stop operations you could control this using `--job-mode=` (e.g. `start --job-mode=replace-irreversibly` or `stop --job-mode=fail`), but it seems that the `restart` subcommand does not correctly propagate the specified job mode, at least not in current systemd versions.